# Meaning of '2> >(command)' Redirection in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

A while ago I made a script and I added some logging around it, but I forgot how the redirection for the logging works :-(

The gist of it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE=/some/path/mylogfile

(
  # here go my commands which produce some stdout
  # and, if something goes wrong, also some stderr
) 1>>${LOGFILE} 2> >( tee -a ${LOGFILE} >&2 )
```

When I run the script, it doesn't print anything to `stdout`, but only prints what goes to `stderr`. Logfile `${LOGFILE}` captures both stdout and stderr.

When I run the script and there is no output on my terminal, then I know everything is fine. If there is any output, I know something went wrong and I can check the logfile to find out what the problem is.

The part of the redirection that now puzzles me is the syntax of: `2> >( some command )`

Can anyone explain what is going on there?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`>(...)` is called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). It lets the "outer" program write to the "inner" program as if it were a file.

In this case it's writing `stderr` to `tee -a ${LOGFILE} >&2` which will append to `LOGFILE` and then also write everything back to `stderr`.

The redirection operator can go in either direction for process substitution, so you can write to it, as in this example, or use `<(...)` to read from it, which is a handy way to, for example, do a `while` loop without running it in a subshell itself.

Comment: Got it :-)  If I execute `echo <(date)`, it gives me the name of the substituted file: `/dev/fd/63`. If I execute `cat <(date)`, it gives me the date, i.e. the content of the substituted file: `Fri Nov 18 14:11:09 NZDT 2016`.

Comment: @NZD, yes - but don't imagine it's a regular file - what you see in `/dev` is a name for the pipe between the processes.

Comment: Is this technique used because stderr cannot be piped (to `tee`, in this case)?

Comment: @bli Yeah, since stdout is already being redirected elsewhere this seems to me like the most straightforward way to `tee` stderr and keep it separate from stdout.